# Not able to convert a value from List<Long> at ith position to long

Tags: java, for-loop, collections

May be this is very simple but I am struggling a lot from hours. I have a list of Long which has got some 100 values in it. I have to loop through this list and have to get the value at ith position in a Long variable.

```
List<Long> dmrIds = (List<Long>)q.getResultList();
```

is my list which is fetching data from DB. I am using a for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<dmrIds.size();i++){
   Long dmrId = dmrIds.get(i).longValue();
   ..........
}
```

When I try to convert into Long, it is giving:

```
`java.math.bigDecimal` can't be converted into `java.lang.Long`
```

I am unable to crack it. Please help.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Are you sure this is the place where the error occurs?

Comment: Obviously your list contains `BigDecimal`s. If there's a bug, it's in `q.getResultList()`.

Comment: @Smutje.. Yes. I am sure about the line causing error. I checked by putting breakpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you're casting the result of `q.getResultList()` to a `List<Long>`, that cast doesn't really check that it's a `List<Long>`... because at execution time, it's really just a `List`. (This is due to type erasure in Java generics.)

It sounds like really it's a `List<BigDecimal>`... so *either* you need to change what `getResultList()` does, *or* you need to handle the fact that it's a `List<BigDecimal>` and deal with the `BigDecimal` values.

You can validate this by iterating over each element and just printing out the type:

```
List<?> results = (List<?>) q.getResultList();
for (Object result : results) {
     System.out.println(result.getClass());
}
```

Or look at it in a debugger, of course.

To get all the values as `long`, you just need to call `longValue()`:

```
List<BigDecimal> results = (List<BigDecimal>) q.getResultList();
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    long result = results.get(i).longValue();
    // ...
}
```

(If you don't actually need the index, I'd suggest using an enhanced for loop instead of explicitly getting each item by index though.)

Comment: Skeet-> Actually I need to convert it into a long as I have to pass long value to a dependent system of my project.That application accepts only Long value. So is there a way to convert the value?

Comment: @SanjayMalhotra: Yes, you can call `BigDecimal.longValue`. But at the moment, you're effectively trying to cast `Long` to `BigDecimal`, and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

While it seems that your list contains `BigDecimal` entries as opposed to `Long` entries, there's actually a couple of ways to go about getting the `long` data you're interested in.

First, you can cast the result to a `List<BigDecimal>`, but this feels like you're taking away one of the major benefits to generics - you don't really need to cast all that often.  Worse, it makes for somewhat unreadable and scary-looking code.

If it really *is* returning a `List<BigDecimal>`, then simply capturing that outright wouldn't be the end of the world.  But, you'd have to do the conversion yourself in the loop using `longValue`.

Your other alternative is to accept a list of something that extends `Number` instead, which may be the cleaner option.  You're going to be extracting its `longValue` anyway, and `Number` already comes with a method to do that.

`BigDecimal` is a subclass of `Number`, so this declaration is legal:

```
List<? extends Number> results = q.getResultList();
for(Number number : results) {
    long dmrId = number.longValue();
    // other processing
}
```

`? extends Number` is a [upper-bounded wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html); it will allow you to create a list that contains anything that is a subclass of `Number`, which again, includes `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on message of exception, your fetching result return java.math.BigDecimal object.
BigDecimal is larger than java.lang.Long and used for huge numbers.

```
List<LBigDecimal> results = (List<LBigDecimal>)q.getResultList();
for(BigDecimal big : results) {
    // do something
    big.add(new BigDecimal(1L);
}
```

Comment: @Vahid-> here again we are adding to bigdecimal object. I want that in Long value.

Comment: I called add for example, I want to say the BigDecimal class has more method for some operations. :)